# How to add items to an existing ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists defined as below.

```
  List userErrorlist = new ArrayList();
  List adminErrorList = new ArrayList(userErrorlist);
```

The second List, `adminErrorList` is an exact copy of the `userErrorList`.

However, I want to add an item to the beginning of the `adminErrorList` before copying the content of the `userErrorList`.

Is that possible?

Comment: What stops you from doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is (add size based on `userErrorlist` for speedup, since it will not be necessary to do resizing, and therefore copying, if `userErrorlist` is larger then 16) :

```
List userErrorlist = new ArrayList();
List adminErrorList = new ArrayList(userErrorlist.size() + 1);


adminErrorList.add(newElement);
adminErrorList.addAll(userErrorlist);
```

or

```
Collections.addAll(adminErrorList, userErrorlist.toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
 ArrayList<Object> newList = new ArrayList<Object>();
 newList.addAll(oldArrayList);
```